# Strategies for userland file encryption without FDE

Tags: freebsd, encryption, laptop, cryptography, encfs

There are cryptography experts that are concerned over using Full Disk Encryption (FDE) on *nix platforms due to attack surface exposed due to reverse engineering of encryption algorithm when looking at common *nix OS files of known size and checksum. I have not yet found any obfuscation techniques to get around this attack surface and thus am considering dropping FDE as a strategy.

I am presently researching just using userland level encryption like PEFS (FreeBSD) or EncFS (*nix).

Assuming that there is no good solution around FDE size/checksum attack surface, what strategies for building up systems should be put in place to ensure that critical security artifacts are kept safe if a hacker gets hands onto the physical hardware when it is shut down or locked?

Answer (score 1):

`PEFS` is probably the best solution for FreeBSD. More information can be found here: https://wiki.freebsd.org/PEFS

Also, there is an interview with the author of PEFS here: http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/53747/p-e-f-s-bsd-29/

Comment: Can you encrypt the root file system with PEFS?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use geli block device encryption on a file mounted as a disk via the md driver using a vnode backing.

Comment: What does the md and vnode backing add to improve geli? Can't a hacker detect md and vnode backing and mount to see the geli?

Comment: I guess the thought that I was trying to express was that you would only put some files that you want encrypted in there, not the whole OS. If the issue is the attacker knows the checksum of your binaries, don't put your binaries in the encryption, just your home directory, for example.

Comment: Yes, that is a very good point regarding FDE. If you encrypt your home partition / slice with a different password, you measurably reduce the risk. However, not all files can be easily moved into the home directory. For instance, keys, virtual disks and other files that may be required on the a computer that is acting like a server in some cases. Many times, these files are sitting in the root file system and not the home directory.